# Dictionaries and listing positions of word in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to take a list and use a dictionary to catalogue where a particular item occurs in a list, as an example:

> L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e']

the dictionary needs to contain the following:

> D = {'a': 0, 5 , 'b': 1, 3 , 'c': 2, 4 , 'e': 6}

However if I use what I wrote:

```
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    if D.has_key('word_list[i]') == False:
        D['word_list[i]'] = i
    else:
        D[word_list[i]] += i
```

Then I get a KeyError for a certain word and I don't understand why I should be getting an error.

Comment: Showing off: `D = dict((k, map(operator.itemgetter(1), v)) for k, v in (itertools.groupby(sorted(x[::-1] for x in enumerate(L)), operator.itemgetter(0))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified you solution a bit to work

```
word_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'e']
dict = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'e': []}
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    if word_list[i] not in dict:
        dict[word_list[i]] = [i]
    else:
        dict[word_list[i]].append(i)
```

Result

```
{'a': [0, 5], 'c': [2, 4], 'b': [1, 3], 'e': [6]}
```

Comment: Your code will work, although it deersve some remarks: (1) you don't need to prepopulat your dict - your code does create new keys for words as they appear; (2) you should use "enumerate" in the for to get both the content of each word an its index number, like `for i, word in enumerate(word_list) `; (3) you should not use `dict` as a variable name in Python code, as it is the dictionary class name - which becomes shadowed

Comment: Aha thank you! However my only question would be: If you are adding new entries if the item does not exist in the dictionary, isn't the:

dict = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'e': []}

superfluous? I only ask because I may need to modify this code to list the positions of words in a book, and I won't be able to list every word that occurs for such a large collection of words. Then again, I know very little of Python but it seems to work with the dict line omitted.

Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't see jsbueno's comment appear, damn.

Comment: @jsbueno I prepopulated the dictionary simple because he did, I know there was no reason to do so. Didn't know about 2 and 3, never really used Python much, I'll keep those in mind in the future.

Answer (score 6):

```
if D.has_key('word_list[i]') == False:
```

Uh, what?

At the very least, you should drop the quotes:

```
if D.has_key(word_list[i]) == False:
```

But you're also misusing a number of Python structures:

1. Why are summing up the indices?
2. Why are you comparing to False?
3. Shouldn't you be using `setdefault`

Like this:

```
for i in range(len(word_list)):
   D.setdefault(word_list[i], []).append(i)
```

Comment: And then spell it `if word_list[i] not in D:`.

Comment: I had that originally, but then from what I can tell it adds the indices of each occurence together instead of listing them. I fail at programming.

Comment: @GeorgeBurrows -- what do you *want* it to do?  The code I posted will set the value at x to the list of all the indices where x appears.

Comment: I was using False so if an item from the list is not present in the dictionary then it gets added?

Also I haven't been taught things such as setdefault so I don't know how to use them.

Comment: The idiomatic way to write that is `if not D.has_key(...`.  In fact, it's generally considered good form when you have an if-else situation to put the "positive" clause first instead of indulging in [code lototes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes).  As for "having been taught" something, read Asimov's "[Profession](http://www.abelard.org/asimov.php)".

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the shortest solution for your problem:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,el in enumerate(L):
    D[el].append(i)

>>> D
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 5], 'c': [2, 4], 'b': [1, 3], 'e': [6]})
```

If you want to stick with `dict`, correcting your code I would came up with:

```
>>> D = {}
>>> for i,el in enumerate(L):
    if el not in D:
        D[el] = [i] #crate a new list
    else:
        D[el].append(i) #appending to the existing list


>>> D
{'a': [0, 5], 'c': [2, 4], 'b': [1, 3], 'e': [6]}
```

Also, there is a `setdefault` method in `dict` which can be used:

```
>>> D = {}
>>> for i,el in enumerate(L):
    D.setdefault(el,[]).append(i)


>>> D
{'a': [0, 5], 'c': [2, 4], 'b': [1, 3], 'e': [6]}
```

But I prefer to use `defaultdict` from `collections`.